# Compiling ffmpeg: how to force it to link to a specific libx264?

Tags: ffmpeg, x264

I'm trying to compile the newest version of ffmpeg (in CentOS 5.3). I first downloaded the latest version of libx264, compiled it with `--enable-static` and installed it in `/usr/local/`. However, when I then compile ffmpeg I get this error message:

```
libavcodec/libavcodec.a(libx264.o): In function `X264_init':
/usr/local/src/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libx264.c:494: undefined reference to `x264_encoder_open_125'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [ffmpeg_g] Error 1
```

Searching on the net, I see that this can happen if ffmpeg is picking up an older version of libx264, which I indeed have (in `/usr/lib`) and can't uninstall because other pieces of software depend on it. The question is then: how can I force ffmpeg to link against the libx264 that I want? The last time I had to do this (admittedly a year ago) I also had 2 versions of libx264, and I don't remember having to do anything special. Is there a configure switch that I'm forgetting?

Comment: You'll want to pass some extra compiler and linker flags so that `/usr/local/` is searched before `/usr/`.  Something like `-I/usr/local/include` and `-L/usr/local/lib`.  Check out the gcc documentation for those flags for more info.

Comment: So do I have to edit the ffmpeg Makefile on my own?

Comment: No.  `configure` has options for passing in additional flags, usually something like `configure --extra-cflags <blah> --extra-ldflags <blah>` or similar.  Should be documented in `configure --help`.

Comment: Thanks, but the only thing I could find in ./configure --help was --extra-cflags and --host-cflags, which didn't look like what I'm looking for (they seemed to be for cross-compiling). In the end I decided to do the easy thing and tempirarily remove the other x264 package before compiling... :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using and android-ffmpeg git project as an [example](https://github.com/halfninja/android-ffmpeg-x264/blob/master/Project/jni/configure_ffmpeg.sh) with static x264 libs, and like 'blahdblah' already said... I think you just need to setup your lib paths correctly in the CC and LINK phases. Notice the 'cflags' and 'ldflags' switches at the bottom of the link.

I don't mean to complicate matters by introducing an android example , but it may help to look at this instance of 'config_ffmpeg'.

Answer (score 0):

are you just trying to decode h264, we have a framework based on ffmpeg .8, which seems a little more stable than the latest

www.github.com/mooncatventures-group